# "Unknown address" when receiving text message on Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, sms

I have Samsung Galaxy S3 and whenever I get a text message from my friend, my phone says "Unknown address" although I've already saved the number. All their messages are kept under "Unknown address", so I can't really find out whose message they are.

I want to receive messages under the right conversation group, how can I fix this?

Comment: The question is a bit confusing, can u assure if ALL the SMS you receive are saved with unknown address, or just the SMS from one contact?